# Is there a command line tool in Unix similar to R's "rank"?

Tags: linux, r, unix, command-line

In R, the function rank "(r)eturns the sample ranks of the values in a vector.".

For instance:

```
rank(c(10, 20, 40, 30, 50, 60))
```

returns

```
1 2 4 3 5 6
```

Unix has a command line sort.
  Does Unix have a command line version of the rank function?

Note about ties: 
  in case of ties, R's rank default behavior is to return the average rank for the tied entries, e.g.

```
rank(c(10, 20, 40, 30, 50, 60, 60))
```

returns

```
1.0 2.0 4.0 3.0 5.0 6.5 6.5
```

Ideally, the command line tool would have the same behavior.

Comment: `Rscript -e "args<-commandArgs(TRUE); print(rank(as.numeric(readLines(args[1]))))" FILENAME`  That's a one-liner you can `alias` and if you need slightly better output it shld be trivial to modify

Comment: `r -e 'print(rank(as.numeric(readLines(argv[1]))))' filename` --- if you use [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) it is even shorter [and starts faster](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2014/09/02/).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Why did you not put them as answers?

Comment: And, is there a way to pipe the data into the RScript as you'd be able to do with sort?